# Utilise different internet connections for Torrents and Web-browsing in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, combine

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a laptop (at my mom's house) so i can use it as an ssh remote server and do my downloads there and other stuff also (like ftp server etc). Lately i've been doing some heavy downloads there (torrents, file sharing sites etc) and that's interfering with my mom's trying to do Web-browsing(Facebook, Google searches, mainly simple stuff).

Is there any way that i can utilise my mobile 4g router for my mom to do the browsing stuff there and the other connection to act like ssh server for me to do the downloads.

I need to utilise both the wifi and ethernet at the same time. The ethernet connects to our home router (ADSL provider) and the wifi i want it to connect to the 4g mobile router.

Comment: You should [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1267182/edit) extra information into your question rather than posting comments.

Comment: If I understand [this answer on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/4890) correctly, using specific network interfaces for specific software is not generally possible on Ubuntu, though hypothetically you could accomplish what you want if you knew specifics about all the IP addresses being used in either application. Still, the answer is somewhat old now, and maybe there is some other way...